# Why can we assume that $X$ is normal to prove the equality in Lazarsfeld?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

In Lazarsfeld's book Positivity in AG I, Example 2.1.16. He considers a proper birational morphism $$
\mu: X^{\prime} \longrightarrow X
$$
of irreducible varieties, with $X^{\prime}$ normal. Let $L$ be a line bundle on $X$, and $E$ a $\mu$-exceptional effective divisor on $X^{\prime}$ (i.e. an effective Cartier divisor on $X^{\prime}$ with the property that each of the irreducible components of the corresponding Weil divisor maps under $\mu$ to a variety of codimension $\geq 2$ in $X$ ). Then the natural inclusion
$$
H^0(X^{\prime}, \mu^* L) \longrightarrow H^0(X^{\prime}, \mu^* L \otimes \mathcal{O}_{X^{\prime}}(E))
$$
is an isomorphism.

He then gives some explanations, **what confuses me is this sentence: one assumes that $X$ is normal.** If we admit this assumption, then this problem can be solved as follows.

Denote the exceptional locus of $\mu$ by $F$.
We then have the displayed inclusions
$$H^0(X,L)\subset H^0(X^\prime,\mu^*L)\subset H^0(X^{\prime}, \mu^* L \otimes \mathcal{O}_{X^{\prime}}(E))\subset H^0(X^{\prime}-F, \mu^* L \otimes \mathcal{O}_{X^{\prime}}(E)),$$
and
$$H^0(X^{\prime}-F, \mu^* L \otimes \mathcal{O}_{X^{\prime}}(E))=H^0(X^{\prime}-F, \mu^* L)= H^0(X-\mu(F),L)=H^0(X,L).$$

The last equivalence needs the normality of $X$. So here is my question again, why can we assume that $X$ is normal??

Comment: $ \mu $ factors through the normalization of $ X $, by the universal property.

Comment: Dear @CraniumClamp, thanks a lot. So here we have a composition $X^\prime\rightarrow\widetilde{X}\rightarrow X$, where $\rho: \widetilde{X}\rightarrow X$ is the normalization. Could you kindly explain for the morphism $f:X^\prime\rightarrow\widetilde{X}$, why $\text{codim}f(F)\geq 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Cranium Clamp, I write the answer here.

**Step one:** Since $\mu$ factors through the normalization of $X$, then we can get the composition $${X^\prime}\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}{\widetilde X}\stackrel{\rho}\longrightarrow X.$$

**Step two:** One obtains that any exceptional divisor $E$ with respect to the morphism $\mu$ is also an exceptional divisor with respect to the morphism $f$ due to the finiteness of $\rho$. Here we have used the fact that the image of a divisor under a finite morphism is still a divisor, see [finite morphisms preserve dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758315/do-finite-morphisms-preserve-dimensions) for example.

Above all, we can transfer the situation to the case when $X$ is normal.